# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string en laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy tratando de pasar el resultado de una consulta desde el controlador usando la facade DB:

```
function gestion_usuario() {


           $usuarios = DB::table('users')
            ->where('role_id', '=', 3)
            ->get();

           
return view('theme.back.gestion-usuarios',compact('usuarios'));
    }
```

a la vista:

```
<table id="zero_config" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#id</th>
          <th>email</th>
         

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach ($usuarios as $item)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{$item->id}}</th>
          <td><a href="">{{$item->email}}</td></a>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>#id</th>        
            <th>email</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error:

**ErrorException
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravelroles\resources\views\theme\back\gestion-usuarios.blade.php)**

La consulta devuelve los resultados correctos, pero sin embargo al pasarlos a la vista da el error.

Answer (score 0):

creo que el error está en que el resultado te está devolviendo una matriz por lo que estas intentando hacer un echo de un array.

Tendrías 2 soluciones en este caso:

- La primera sería realizar un echo del elemento del array concreto que deseas imprimir de esta manera:

```js
    @foreach ($usuarios as $item)
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{$item[0]->id}}</th>
              <td><a href="">{{$item[0]->email}}</td></a>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Con esto te aseguras de que accedes al primer registro que te devuelve, ya que tu has hecho un where que tu sabes que devuelve un resultado, pero el programa sabe que se podría obtener más de un resultado por lo que lo devuelve como un array bidimensional.

- La segunda opción sería modificar la consulta:

```js
function gestion_usuario() {


           $usuarios = DB::table('users')
            ->where('role_id', '=', 3)
            ->first();

           
return view('theme.back.gestion-usuarios',compact('usuarios'));
    }
```

Con esto te aseguras de que la consulta te devuelve como resultado solo el primer registro que encuentra, por lo que te lo devuelve como un array ordinario.

Comment: Me sigue dando error, en el primer caso --> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.  En el segundo caso -->Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: @ricky ¿podrías hacer un var_dump($usuarios) en la vista y poner lo que te imprime? Así seguro que lo resolvemos

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#375 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(13) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1097 (12) { ["id"]=> int(5) ["name"]=> string(8) "usuario3" ["email"]=> string(21) "usuario3@usuario3.com" ["email_verified_at"]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$tA.7lcsqtvEElAGQFkBLS.I7VU91SEC2WHL8EIJVleB/AXWq8/zQO" ["two_factor_secret"]=> NULL ["two_factor_recovery_codes"]=> NULL ["activo"]=> int(0) ["remember_token"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2021-05-13 16:14:47" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2021-05-13 16:14:47" ["role_id"]=> int(3) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#368 (12)...